# Is it possible to query records for specific day using user specified time_zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm setting the global timezone per user like this:

```
around_filter :user_time_zone, :if => :current_user

def user_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

I'm creating some records, and when I inspect them, the created_at field seems to be using the correct time_zone, e.g, with "Caracas" timezone:

```
[#<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4e58
  id: "89c12856-4180-41ba-be4c-e1d555cd4b5c",
  description: "New timer",
  created_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 11:51:43 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 11:51:54 VET -04:30>,
 #<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4d18
  id: "8d8598e1-910d-4d89-898e-3de3cdf021c1",
  description: "Connecting the timer hours with projects",
  created_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:30:11 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:30:11 VET -04:30>,
 #<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4bd8
  id: "29e67663-e538-41e3-ba4e-0d02d3431abc",
  description: "Test completing 2 hours",
  created_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:30:47 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:31:08 VET -04:30>,
 #<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4a98
  id: "2260c971-c4e0-4ae0-97df-672cdeeac65a",
  description: "Working on project details",
  created_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:50:55 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:50:55 VET -04:30>,
 #<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4958
  id: "bfe5189d-5124-47c9-ba6d-2f28a08e6c5f",
  description: "Working",
  created_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 19:44:07 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 19:44:22 VET -04:30>,
 #<TimeEntry:0x007f6658ed4818
  id: "23b3fd5d-8be4-40b7-a9b9-d48e1fe6816d",
  description: "New timer",
  created_at: Sat, 26 Mar 2016 19:51:10 VET -04:30,
  updated_at: Sat, 26 Mar 2016 19:51:41 VET -04:30>]
```

There are 5 records on '2016-03-25' and 1 on '2016-03-26'. I'm trying to fetch them by day like this:

```
day = '2016-03-25'
@project.time_entries.where("date_trunc('day', created_at) = ?", day).count
```

However, I'm getting the wrong results, I'm getting 4 records on 25th, 1 record on 26th and 1 more on 27th. It seems like the `created_at` field is using the default time_zone (which is UTC, and there's an offset of '+4:30' from the time_zone i'm testing this with).

How can I fetch records for an specific day using the time_zone I set?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this, instead of using a string conditional, I'm using a range condition:

```
total_time = @project.time_entries.where(created_at: (day.beginning_of_day..day.end_of_day)).count
```